# SQL Server Mangement Studioにてデータベースフォルダが展開できなくなる。

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Management StudioにてDatabaseフォルダが開かない (展開中... もしくは expanding...) の状態から進まない

**環境**
Windows 10 Pro x64 2004 (1903から更新)
SQL Server 2012 SP4, 2014, 2016SP1(上記Windows 10にインストール)

そしてなぜか以下のコマンドを実行すると治ります。

```
use master select * from sys.databases　や select * from @@version
```

Windows Update で 2004 へ更新後に発生したため、この更新が影響していると思われます。
Windows 10 (2004) はリリースされたばかりで情報が少ないためか日本語、英語でも検索してそれらしき情報が見つかりませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: "Windows Update 2004" とは Windows 10 を使っているということでしょうか？

Comment: >cubick そうです。Windows 10 Pro x64です。またSQL Server本体はそのWindowsにインストールしています。ちなみにSQL Serverのバージョンは2012 SP4, 2014, 2016 SP1いずれも発生しました。トリガーがWindows Updateである可能性が高いです。(私の社内でほとんどの人がUpdate後に発生したため)

Comment: 質問に関わる情報は本文に直接追記してください。また、Windows Update の影響が疑われる場合には「以前のバージョンに戻す」を試すのも一つの方法かと思います。 https://pc-karuma.net/windows-10-restore-previous-version/ / 2004 の配信が始まったばかりなので、不具合関連の情報はまだ少ないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 質問本文に環境を追記しました。前のバージョンに戻せればよいのですが、会社内で管理しているもののため、簡単に直せない状況です。

Answer (score 0):

スクリーンショットで伏せられている接続文字列に問題があると思います。画像を見る限り、`なんとか.master` という名前で登録されているようですが、 `ping なんとか.master` は成功しますか？ つまり、正常に名前解決できますか？
ちなみに、S[QL Server本体とManagement Studioとが同一マシンの場合、`.`や`(local)` というサーバー名で接続](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/logging-in-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)します。そうすることで共有メモリプロトコルで接続できます。ホスト名を指定した場合はTCP/IPプロトコルになります。

Comment: スクリーンショットで伏せている部分はPC名(ex. M110110のような)になります。またping + PC名でもping疎通が確認とれているので名前解決は問題ないと思っています。　共有メモリプロトコルやTCP/IPの接続の設定(SqlServer Configuration Mangerの設定)を確認してみます。

Comment: Windows Updateにより、Firewallの設定がなにか変わりTCP/IP接続で使用していたポートが閉ざされた可能性があります。ただし、上記のクエリ「SELECT @@VERSION」を実行しただけで直ることが理解できません。sys関係に関するクエリを実行すると利用するポートが変わるのでしょうか…